# Calculate AVG of each Month excluding Months w/zeroes

Tags: mysql

I have the following working query that sums the length column/values for each month.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 1 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 2 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 3 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mar',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 4 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Apr',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 5 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 6 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 7 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 8 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 9 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 10 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 11 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblcm.omActCompDate, '%m') = 12 THEN (tblcm.Lgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec',
   SUM(tblcm.Lgth) AS Total
```

giving me the following:

```
Jan 13050
Feb 5200
Mar 48450
Apr 34041
May 38000
Jun 0
Jul 0
Aug 0
Sep 0
Oct 0
Nov 0
Dec 0
```

How can I get the AVG of only the months greater than zero?

- I tried: avg(nullif(tblcm.Lgth, 0)) as m_Avg but get 1825
- I also tried: avg(case when tblcm.Lgth = 0 then null else tblcm.Lgth end) as m_Avg but also get 1825
- I need to get 27748 (which is the SUM of Jan thru May totals, divided by 5 months)

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Do you need to get the average _and_ the monthly sum breakdowns from the same query? Or are you really only concerned with the average right now? Or can you use one query to accomplish one and another query to accomplish the other?

Comment: Something like: `SUM(tblcm.Lgth) / COUNT(DISTINCT IF(tblcm.Lgth=0, NULL, MONTH(tblcm.omActCompDate))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you'll need a subquery to do that. The following assumes that your original query is correct as posted and functions as you said. This is untested, and your probably could have included some more details in your question, so let me now if this doesn't suit your needs.

```
SELECT AVG(sumLgth) AS avgLgth, SUM(sumLgth) AS totalLgth,
    SUM(CASE WHEN theMonth = 1 THEN (tbl.sumLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan',
    SUM(CASE WHEN theMonth = 2 THEN (tbl.sumLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb',
    ...
FROM (
    SELECT MONTH(omActCompDate) AS theMonth, SUM(lgth) AS sumLgth
    FROM tblcm
    GROUP BY MONTH(omActCompDate)
    HAVING sumLgth > 0
) tbl
```

Comment: This should work too.  Though might want .sumLgth in SELECT columns not .lgth

Comment: @ebyrob Good catch. I aliased the columns after the original write-up.

Comment: ebyrob, your solution worked best because I needed to use it with the rest of my query code. (Yes, I needed the month sums plus the avg) 

Final code that worked: 
-----------------------
SUM(tblcm.Lgth) / COUNT(DISTINCT IF(tblcm.Lgth=0, NULL, MONTH(tblcm.omActCompDate)))

(was missing a third closing parenthesis..)

ps: Thanks PatrickQ for the help.. much appreciated!

Comment: ebyrob, just noticed that I need to refine this solution: 

- I really just need to "exclude the Months" that are in the "future".
- so for example when "current month = May" I need the AVG of Jan-May (including zeroes), even if a month may have a "0"